# Data stored in different lines on a file, how to load them as parameters to a class?

Tags: java, initialization, bufferedreader, readline

I'm trying to do a small sentence translator, each sentence has one or more translations that will be loaded from a file formatted like this:

```
EN – english sentence 1

IT – italian translation 1

EN – english sentence 2

IT – italian translation 1

IT – italian translation 2
```

these information should be loaded as parameters in this class:

```
public class Sentence {

    private String fraseENG;
    private ArrayList<String> translations = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean correct;


    public void setFraseENG(String fraseENG) {
        this.fraseENG = fraseENG;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation){
        translations.add(translation);
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble deciding when to initiate the class Sentence while reading from file.

```
public ArrayList<Sentence> getFrasi() {

    ArrayList<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
    File file = new File(filename);

    try {
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line=reader.readLine();

        while(line!=null){

            String[] readLine = line.split("-");
            String lang = readLine[0];
            String sentence = readLine[1];

            Sentence sentenceClass = new Sentence();

            if(lang.equals("EN")){

                sentenceClass.setFraseENG(sentence);

            }else{
                sentenceClass.setTranslation(readLine[1]);
            }
            sentences.add(sentenceClass);
            line=reader.readLine();

        }
        reader.close();

    } catch //TODO

    return sentences;
}
```

This way, however, I have a new class whenever I read a new line. How should I do it? Thank you

Comment: trim your strings because there is a space between EN and '-'.

Comment: Your while loop should contain `line = reader.readLine();` to keep the reading going. Right now it will keep working on the same line forever.

Comment: In fact it is better to create your objects while reading

Comment: @MartinMJ yes thank you, I forgot it.

Comment: @DAO it works just fine even with spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new `Sentence` instance only if the english string was found and declare it outside the while loop:

```
Sentence sentenceClass = null;

while(line!=null) {
  // file reading part  

  if (lang.equals("EN")){
    sentenceClass = new Sentence();
    sentences.add(sentenceClass);             
    sentenceClass.setFraseENG(sentence);
  } 
  else {
    sentenceClass.setTranslation(readLine[1]);
  }

  line=reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Aren't translations added to sentenceClass after sentenceClass has already been stored in the ArrayList this way?

Comment: Yes, translations will be added until a new 'EN' was found, then a new `Sentence` will be created with this EN part and all following 'IT's will be added to the new created `Sentence`

Comment: @Bianca It's not a copy which is added to the `ArrayList` it's a reference so the object stored in the `ArrayList` is changed even after adding it to the list - (if this is what your comment was about)

Answer (score 0):

Nest two `while` loops, the outer one to create new `Sentence`s, the inner one to add translations to the current sentence. Like this:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null) {
    Sentence sentence = new Sentence();
    String[] readLine = line.split(" - ");
    String lang = readLine[0];
    String phrase = readLine[1];
    sentence.setFraseENG(phrase);

    line = reader.readLine();
    while(line != null) {
        readLine = line.split(" - ");
        lang = readLine[0];
        phrase = readLine[1];
        if(!"IT".equals(lang)) {
            // not a translation, break and create a new sentence
            break;
        }
        sentence.setTranslation(phrase);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    sentences.add(sentence);
}
```

This assumes that the first line and anything that doesn't start with `"IT"` is an English phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The way the code is written looks alright. Let it be a new class everytime, this is the correct way to insert into arraylist for every loop. Garbage collector will take care of cleaning the redundant objects.